# Qt Download + Build on Mac

Tags: qt, macos, open-source, build, pyqt

all. I downloaded the Qt source, and then proceeded to start building it on a Mac. At the moment, it's been four hours. Is it supposed to take this long? If not, what am I doing wrong? It's just building, building, building, building.... And using a lot of resources. It's  confusing.

Comment: why not download pre-complied binaries or installers? Building Qt from source exactly takes much time.

Comment: What mac have you got and how much memory - and why not use the precompiled version http://qt.nokia.com/downloads ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is meant to take this long.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the use of parallel make. 
make -j4 uses 4 CPUs.